# How to read a binary file (created in c++) in MATALB. (the file include two headers and one data))

Tags: matlab, binary, header

I want to read a huge data which includes 3 segments(2 headers and 1 data). But when I use fopen and fread  in MATLAB it doesn't work. Could you help how I can read the file?

Regards,
Majid

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read binary files in Matlab like the following:

```
 fileID = fopen('fileName.bin');
 A = fread(fileID);
 fclose(fileID);
```

See more details [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html).